# Naxam MapBox Plugin not rendering the Map when switching offline and online Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, mapbox

After Downloading the Tiles and loading the map Offline, If we make the app online and then offline after that if you navigate to the Map page , The map doesn't load.

On debugging we found in the above scenario also the GetMapAsync() is being called but we are not getting the OnMapReady() call back. Even the base OnMapReady() is not being invoked

Naxam.Mapbox.Droid version used is 6.4.0.1
Device tested: lenovo k6 Power
OS: android

Steps to Trigger Behavior

1. Launch the app online
2. Click on Navigate to the Map page
3. Click on Offline storage and download to download the tiles.
4. After the above is completed navigate the back.
5. Make the app offline and navigate to the map page, You can see the map loads.
6. Navigate back make the app online and then offline after a few seconds.
7. Navigate back to the map page.
8. You will see the map doesn't load

Link to Demonstration
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1cWMxQrCvFwiecmNX0rMPBhBti1_psFoJ

Expected Behavior
From the user perspective the map should load.
From Dev perspective since the below code is getting executed

code:

```
         fragment = new MapViewFragment();
        activity.SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction()
        .Replace(view.Id, fragment)
        .CommitAllowingStateLoss();
        fragment.GetMapAsync(this);
```

We expect the OnMapReady() callback should be invoked

Actual Behavior
The Map doesn't load.
neither the OnMapReady() call back nor the OnMapReady() override is been called.

Note:- At step 6 we saw the following in the output. Not sure it is relevant.
05-11 12:59:41.198 I/mbgl ( 4437): {DefaultFileSour}[Database]: Unable to make space for entry

Help Needed....